# Could not display "/media/...".The location is not a folder

Tags: root

i have installed ubuntu 12.10 (64 bit) beside my windows 7(64 bit) via wubi.i have just increased the size of root.disk via wubi manual but when i log into ubuntu i can not mount my windows ntfs drives it says :

Could not display "/media/...".The location is not a folder.

even i can not do anything out of my home folder in file system drive,like copy,cut and past files! how can i fix it without installing ubuntu again?i don't have live cd and i have installed ubuntu from booted USB drive.

thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem and ran the following command in terminal to fix it:

```
sudo chown user:user /media/user/
```

Just replace `user` with your username. Good luck!

Comment: Replace which user with username because there are three user in your command.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the user permission by using chmod command

```
sudo chmod 775 /media/user
```

where *user* is the *username* of your account

Answer (score 0):

On personal Windows systems you usually have access to the whole system and drive because you have administrator access. Linux based systems like Ubuntu have much stricter security to prevent bad things from happening.

If you want to get administrator access (a.k.a. root access) on a Ubuntu system you can use the command `sudo`. Prefixing a command line with `sudo` will run that program as root. The command `sudo -i` will give you an interactive shell as root.

But unless you know what you are doing: be careful. Having root access gives you a lot of power, including the power to mess up your system :-)

Comment: thanks for your reply Sander but previously when i haven't increase the root.disk size i had no problem to open my local drives in ubuntu,even now with root access i can't open them?

Comment: Sounds like a mounting error then, but can't tell you what went wrong based on the information you give here. Can you check /var/log/syslog to see if there is an error message about htis there?